# Discharging a capacitor into another capacitor via inductor

Tags: capacitor, inductor, discharge, charge

What would happen if you connect a charged capacitor (charged to V voltage) with another capacitor of same rating via inductor. What would happen ? Will both capacitors will have same voltage and if yes, then what would it be ?

Comment: You can move energy from one place to another but you always loose some…

Answer (score 4):

The two capacitors and inductor would form a series tuned circuit. The initial energy in the pre-charged capacitor would circulate in the three components and, a sinewave oscillation would result that carries on for infinite time without decay (if ideal components are used). If non-ideal components are used then, their resistive losses would ebb away at the energy and the sinewave would gradually reduce in amplitude. It's easy enough to prove in a simulation package: -

[image]

[image]